Error while printing the contents by reading a binary file in c++
I created a binary file and inserted some data inside it. I am trying to read it but I am not getting the desired output.
Below is the c++ code:
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 80;
int main(){
    int buffer[MAX];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++){
        buffer[i] = i;
    }

    ofstream winfile;
    winfile.open("text.dat", ios::binary);
    winfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), MAX * sizeof(int));
    winfile.close();

    fstream rinfile;
    rinfile.open("text.dat", ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++){
        buffer[i] = 0; 
    }

    rinfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), MAX * sizeof(int));
    rinfile.close();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++){
        cout << buffer[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}


The output I am getting is :

What is the possible reason for this, or are there any errors in my code?

Try using std::ifstream instead of std::fstream. Also, don't forget to check for errors, like e.g. if (!rinfile.read(...)) { /* Error */ }

such a blunder i did :p

Don't keep us in suspense, what was your blunder?
