Error while printing the total bytes present in a binary file in c++
A class Person is there and am writing the data from it to a group.dat file and then checking the total numbers of person's data present in it.
I have written a code in c++ to calculate the total persons data present in the binary file
Below is the code
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Person{
    char name[80];
    int age;
    public:
        void setData(){
            cout<<"enter the name ";cin>>name;
            cout<<"enter the age ";cin>>age;
        }
        void getData(){
            cout<<"the name is :"<<name<<" and the age is :"<<age<<endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Person p;
    char ch;
    fstream file;
    file.open("group.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    do {
        p.setData();
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p),sizeof(p));
        cout<<"to enter more data press y or Y : "; cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y' || ch == 'Y');

    file.seekg(0); // Move to the beginning of the file
    while(file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(p))){
        p.getData();
    }

    // calculating total persons in the data

    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int pos = file.tellg();
    cout<<pos<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(p)<<endl;
    int n = pos / sizeof(p);

    cout<<"the total number of persons are: "<<n<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}

the error it is displaying is the value of pos = -1
below is the ss 

tellg will return -1 on error.

that is also in the ouput as well. What do i need to do in order to get the total bytes of the file to calculate the total numbers of persons.
My professor told me in this way only but it's not working.

First try flushing the file. Second, try using different streams for output and input, closing the output file before reading it back in again.

What do i need to do in order to get the total bytes of the file -- std::filesystem::file_size.  All that stuff you're doing now has been already taken care of by the implementors of your C++ compiler's standard library, assuming you are using C++17 or higher.

what changes i need to make in my program so that the value of pos is the total bytes not -1

@DEADPØØLGAMING Again, what is the issue with not using std::filesystem::file_size?  My professor told me in this way -- Your professor is not up to date with the current C++ standard library.  Coding using tellg to get the file size in C++ is obsolete and only should be used for legacy purposes.  Are you using a C++17 compliant compiler?  If so, all you need to do is call file_size and divide that by sizeof(Person).  Simpler and to the point, no dealing with tellg, pos being -1, etc.

Voting to close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78891638/error-while-printing-the-contents-by-reading-a-binary-file-in-c

Your problem is with reading until it fails here
while(file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(p))){
    p.getData();
}

After hitting the wall, the file will remember that it is in a failed state, and will not try any other I/O-operations until the failure has been cleared.
Luckily, clearing the state is as simple as adding a line
file.clear();

before calling seekg.

You can also get rid of the seekg since the read loop already read to the end of the file, so the seekg is basically a no-op.
